# How do I test if merging two websites is a good idea?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, usability-testing

Client wants to merge two of his websites; one is into retail and the other export. Two distinct audiences no doubt. My bias tells me it isn't good to but I want to be sure. What do I test with?  Does a user interview suffice or I do a usability study? i.e a new wireframe combining the two functionalities on a single website.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, I think we'll be able to help you with methodologies if you can edit your question to tell us what you need to find out. What are the metrics or user experience factors you think the merge will affect negatively?

Comment: How will the sites be merged? There are so many variables at play and you will need to be more specific about the changes involved.